# Why does my array value not get stored and dissapears

Tags: python

When I try to add a note, and view it after, the value that I put in dissapears and it is not shown in the array. When I input view, I want it to show all the notes I have put in.

```
while 1:
     user = input("Do you want to (View/Add) notes: ").lower()
     noteList = []
     def addNote():
      global note
      note = input("Add your notes here: ")
      noteList.append(note)
      print(noteList)
     if user == 'view':
       print(noteList)
     elif user == 'add':
       addNote()
       state = True
```

Comment: You are running `noteList = []` on every iteration.

Comment: Every time you start your loop, you reset `noteList` to an empty array.  You probably want to move that initialization outside of the while loop.  Also, there's no need to use `global note`.

Comment: @KlausD. Tyyy :)

Answer (score 1):

It's because you create a new noteList in every loop.

Just move `noteList=[]` out of your loop and it will be fine.

```
noteList = []

while 1:
     user = input("Do you want to (View/Add) notes: ").lower()
     def addNote():
      global note
      note = input("Add your notes here: ")
      noteList.append(note)
      print(noteList)
     if user == 'view':
       print(noteList)
     elif user == 'add':
       addNote()
       state = True
```